# What's the problem with "Colonization hundreds of years ago is held accountable for such situation"?

Tags: syntax, adverbial-phrases, modifiers, adjectivals

I wrote the following sentence.

> Colonization hundreds of years ago is held accountable for such situation.

I think I have used "hundreds of years ago" as a modifier of "colonization" while it is primarily an adverb used with verbs. Is my assumption correct, or there are other problems?

A better alternative I can think of:

> Colonization taken place hundreds of years ago is held accountable for such situation.

What are your recommendations? If "hundreds of years ago” is not an adverbial phrase, which grammatical role does it play?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with "Colonization hundreds of years ago". It's the rest which is problematic. It's clear what you mean, but you've used the wrong phrases. You hold people and organisations accountable, not the activities they do. And _such situation_ is barely grammatical. It either needs to be _such a situation_, or a more direct _this/the current situation_.

Comment: Sorry folks... Colonization cannot be held accountable for anything whatsoever.  Only people and groups with people in them can be held accountable.  Parallelism, glorification, colonization, and cleanliness cannot be held accountable, kapish?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Adjectives and Adverbs

To tell apart adjectives and adverbs, "the adverb questions" are a handy tool. Asking the right ones helps you identify the adverbs in a sentence.

| Sentence | Question | Answer (Adverb) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Sam freed up the clog with a plunger. | ***How** did Sam free up the clog?* | *With a plunger.* |
| Max barely studies. | ***To what extent** does Max study?* | *Barely.* |
| Last week, Alex visited China. | ***When** did Alex visit China?* | *Last week.* |
| Jordan, come here with your assignment. | ***Where**?* | *Here.* |
| Ezra became a doctor to help people. | ***Why** did Ezra become a doctor?* | *To help people.* |

You were right: hundreds of years ago is usually an adverb of time. However, here it is not one. An illustration:

| Sentence | Question | Adverb |
| --- | --- | --- |
| The Vietnam War ended over 30 years ago.¹ | ***When** did the Vietnam War end?* | *Thirty years ago.* |
| Gabriel thought back to the three items he'd discovered in her jewelry box: the compass, a soul and the tarnished ring he gave her hundreds of years ago.² | ***When** did he give her the ring?* | *Hundreds of years ago.* |
| Colonization hundreds of years ago is held accountable for such situation. | ***What kind of** colonisation?* is the sensible question here. | None (unless we change the sentence to *Hundreds of years ago, colonisation was responsible for such a situation* and alter its meaning). |

Now it is fair to assume *hundreds of years ago* is filling the adjectival position. That brings us to the second half under this header: adjectives.

Usage under the next heading implies `N * of years ago` is rarely used as a noun unit. Far more common is `N from * of years ago`:

> - Tree rings reveal **forest fires from hundreds of years ago**
>   — [ScienceDaily](https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2011/09/110907124401.htm)
> - The fossil **creatures from hundreds of millions of years ago** that are known to have utilized live birth are all fairly large, probably apex, predators.
>   — [*The Evolution of the Human Placenta*](https://books.google.com.bd/books?id=xfffGC3hjPoC&pg=PA51&dq=%22*+from+hundreds+of+years+ago%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjBzu6KqaruAhXymeYKHe1XCxc4FBDoATAFegQIBRAC) by Michael L. Power and Jay Schulkin
> - Characterizing **conditions from hundreds of years ago** is substantially more difficult.
>   — [*Historical Environmental Variation in Conservation and Natural Resource Management*](https://books.google.com.bd/books?id=HiZICXcpGQsC&pg=PA182&dq=%22*+from+hundreds+of+years+ago%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiz1OGCqqruAhXFXCsKHZ5zAFcQ6AEwCXoECAkQAg#v=onepage&q=%22*%20from%20hundreds%20of%20years%20ago%22&f=false) by John A. Wiens, Gregory D. Hayward, Hugh D. Safford, and Catherine Giffen

---

¹ collected from [here](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/ago)
² collected from [here](https://sentence.yourdictionary.com/ago)

---

## Usage of `N * of years ago`

Here is some usage of this form where `* of years ago` is strictly an adjective.

> Everything we've checked out so far says that supernovae **billions of years ago** look very similar to the ones of today.¹
> — [*Exploding stars tell all*](https://astronomy.com/issues/1998/november-1998) by Robert Irion in *Astronomy: November 1998*
> It enabled me to look back to the remote past, into the material records of man's efforts **hundreds of years ago**, and contrast them with the modern progress of arts and sciences.
> — [Engineer: An Autobiography](https://books.google.com.bd/books?id=GsSJCvavp4UC&pg=PA162&lpg=PA162&dq=%22It+enabled+me+to+look+back+to+the+remote+past,+into+the+material+records+of+man%27s+efforts+hundreds+of+years+ago,+and+contrast+them+with+the+modern+progress+of+arts+and+sciences.%22&source=bl&ots=DutX1R_8aJ&sig=ACfU3U0ysz9NazenUCmTAVVyqNLcesjxiA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwin_cySoqruAhXf63MBHTXDAgAQ6AEwAXoECAcQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22It%20enabled%20me%20to%20look%20back%20to%20the%20remote%20past%2C%20into%20the%20material%20records%20of%20man%27s%20efforts%20hundreds%20of%20years%20ago%2C%20and%20contrast%20them%20with%20the%20modern%20progress%20of%20arts%20and%20sciences.%22&f=false) by James Nasmyth

**However, compared to its use with `* of years ago` as an adverb, the other usage is rare in [COHA](https://www.english-corpora.org/coha/).** For example,

> John Quincy Adams **thirty years ago** declared that ....
> — [*New Departure of the Republican Party*](https://www.theatlantic.com/magazine/archive/1871/01/new-departure-of-the-republican-party/520173/) by Henry Wilson in *Atlantic Monthly: January 1871*

---

¹ Note this is also correct should *look* have been a transcribing error for *looked*; however, then *billions of years ago* is likely an adverb.

---

## Your sentence

The improvable parts are three in number.

### *Colonization hundreds of years ago*

Some noteworthy points here:

- If this colonisation has been referenced before, use "the colonisation".
- According to the first heading, "Colonisation from hundreds of years ago" is a better choice. It will be understood easily by many people.
  By contrast, "Colonisation hundreds of years ago" is still understandable though rarer. One might consider it for more formal documents.

### *Is held accountable*

Some thoughts on the passive voice used here:

- *Who holds colonisation accountable?* goes unanswered. One should not use the passive voice to avoid taking responsibility for a claim. Besides, the active voice is more clear.
  One should (a) mention the party (Let us call it Responsible Party), as in "Responsible Party holds Colonisation responsible ..." or (b) cite an authoritative source where this claim is justified, as in "Dogs can relieve stress.[¹](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/336698612_Paws_for_Thought_A_Controlled_Study_Investigating_the_Benefits_of_Interacting_with_a_House-Trained_Dog_on_University_Students_Mood_and_Anxiety)"

### *Such situation*

The key problem here:

- Here, you use "situation" as an abstract noun. However, you really mean to use the countable [*situation*](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/situation). This calls for using "such a situation".

### Alternatives

The following form, which uses Responsible Party as a pseudonym, is one candidate.

> Responsible Party holds colonization from hundreds of years ago accountable for such a situation.

Another alternative in case you wish to be subtler:

> Colonization from hundreds of years ago is held accountable for such a situation.¹
> (where "¹" points to a footnote)

You could combine the footnote and the active voice for what I think is the best variant.

Comment: Excellent answer! But "hundreds of years ago" can both be an adj and an adverb?

Comment: @Phantomwagerwallowgiltopus It's not a standard adjective. Omitting words in adjectives is sometimes okay, as in *This is a statue (that was) carved out of stone*. By the same token, *This is colonisation (that was) hundreds of years ago* is okay. The problem is, in the first sentence, *was carved* is in the passive whereas, in *was hundreds of years ago*, *was* is a stative verb meaning *existed*. This is still a long shot. I would not use *colonisation hundreds of years ago* as it is confusing, unidiomatic and the implicit words unclear. Usage agrees, as it is rare as an adjective.

Comment: I get it. Thanks, can I add your skype or something so that I can send you some of my writing, if you don't mind

Answer (score 2):

I take it that someone has told you there is an error.  My first idea is that they want you to put the article "a" before *situation*.  Some might think it unnecessary, but as an American speaker I think you want it - ***unless*** you are talking about the location that a colony literally is situated in.  Even then, just to avoid someone interpreting *situation* as *state of affairs* or *condition*, you might just use *for being thus situated* instead.

As another answerer points out, the phrase you describe as adverbial is not... it might help for me to say that "colonization" is a noun, not a verb, so the phrase would be adjectival, not adverbial.

Below there you should say "An alternative I think is better", as otherwise you sound like you are saying you are an authority on what is best... also I don't think it is better (just the same but longer I'd say), but I think it is acceptable grammatically.  To be safe, "which took place" or "having taken place" wouldn't hurt.

Do you think the "a" is what was considered erroneous?

Comment: After u have pointed it out, now I know it is a mistake. But initially I thought "hundreds of years ago" was an adv

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what you are saying; "hundreds of years ago" is not an adverb. "Colonization hundreds of years ago" is perfectly correct.

Your "better alternative" is in fact worse; you would need to say something like "Colonization, which took place hundreds of years ago, is ...".

However there is a problem in both sentences: you can't say "such situation". You possibly meant "such a situation", although that is also a bit clumsy. Probably the best would just be "this situation".

Comment: appreciate your explanation, then what grammatical part does "hundreds of years ago”？ If it is not an adverbial phrase.

Answer (score 0):

> Colonization hundreds of years ago is held accountable for such situation.   (incorrect)

*Colonization hundreds of years ago is held accountable for such **a situation.***  (a specific situation)

*Colonization hundreds of years ago is held accountable for **such situations**.*  (all of a number of such situations)

> Colonization taken place hundreds of years ago is held accountable ... (incorrect)

Colonization that took place hundreds of years ago is held accountable ...

Answer (score -1):

> Colonization hundreds of years ago is held accountable for such
> situation.

Colonization cannot be held responsible for anything.  Colonialists, on the other hand, can be held to account.

Furthermore, we do not generally think of colonization as a situation.  Instead, we think of it as an aggressive act.  However, we could speak of the situations that colonization caused, causes, or may cause.